# `item-right` is not working inside button element of `ion-col`

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic2

I want to display `name="ios-navigate"` (which is showing as a `navigation icon` in bellow image) right side in the column partition. I have given `item-right` attribute to the `button` element inside 'ion-col' but its not working.

Its currently displaying bellow,

[image]

```
<ion-item>
   <ion-row>
      <ion-col width-33>
         <button style="padding: 0px 0px;" [disabled]="!item.Website" ion-button icon-left clear item-right (click)="RedirectWebsite(item.Website)">
            <ion-icon name="md-globe"   item-left large></ion-icon>
            WWW
         </button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col width-33>
         <button ion-button icon-left clear item-right [disabled]="!item.Phone"  (click)="dialNumber(item.Phone)">
            <ion-icon name="md-call" color="primary" item-left large></ion-icon>
            Phone
         </button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col  width-33>
         <button ion-button  item-right icon-left clear  (click)="GetRoute(item.geometry.location.lat,item.geometry.location.lng)">
            <ion-icon icon-right  name="ios-navigate" color="primary" large></ion-icon>
         </button>
      </ion-col>
   </ion-row>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the latest [`ion-grid`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Grid/) API based on flexbox. `width-*` is deprecated for `col-*`. Also `item-left` and `item-right` attributes work for `ion-item` elements.
You need to use [row attributes](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Row/#row-attributes).Try `justify-content-end` to align horizontally right.

```
<ion-row justify-content-end>
      <ion-col col-4>
         <button style="padding: 0px 0px;" [disabled]="!item.Website" ion-button icon-left clear (click)="RedirectWebsite(item.Website)">
            <ion-icon name="md-globe"   item-left large></ion-icon>
            WWW
         </button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-4>
         <button ion-button icon-left clear [disabled]="!item.Phone"  (click)="dialNumber(item.Phone)">
            <ion-icon name="md-call" color="primary" item-left large></ion-icon>
            Phone
         </button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col  col-4>
         <button ion-button icon-left clear  (click)="GetRoute(item.geometry.location.lat,item.geometry.location.lng)">
            <ion-icon icon-right  name="ios-navigate" color="primary" large></ion-icon>
         </button>
      </ion-col>
   </ion-row>
```